# Flutter - VS Code Debug Console Spam - Red error messages are missing

Tags: debugging, flutter

Hey since the last Flutter update I have been missing error messages of all kinds and my debug console is only spammed with the logs from background processes that are unimportant to me...
At the moment I can only find errors in my code through systematic printing, which is very tedious, especially because its difficult to find them in the spam of all the background processes!
has someone the same problem?
thx

FLUTTER VERSION [Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and couldn't find a fix. For now, I adivse you to just downgrade to v1.12.13+hotfix.7 by running `git checkout v1.12.13+hotfix.7` in your flutter directory.